# How to display URL Encoded text in plain text format in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a comment field in my .NET 4.5 web application and storing the comments in db in url encoded format.

Eg:

> Hi
>
> Hello

The above comment is stored as **hi%0A%0Ahello**

Now, while retrieving the comment I  use

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Comment)
```

which displays the comment as **Hi Hello** (in a single line.)

1. What should I do to display the comments in the way they were entered including line breaks, if any.
2. Is my way of storing the comment in the db correct?

Despite my efforts I couldn't find a similar question. If they've been already answered, please direct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any reason why you want to be storing the content as URL encoded, there is no real benefit to this (in fact, it can consume more space this way)

I would recommend using a varchar field in the database (unless you have lots of international users, in which case, use nvarchar instead.

If the text is simply the contents of a TextArea rendered back out to the page, then simply wrap the content with **<pre>** tags

For example, the following will output two different results:

```
<div>This is some test information
Which is actually split
Onto multiple lines
</div>
<br/><br/>
<pre>This is some test information
Which is actually split
Onto multiple lines
</pre>
```

As shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/H8UyT/

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm storing in url encoded format because I send the comment via jquery ajax (i remember having problems with html characters once) and  I'm also not able to capture the <br/> from the textarea using jquery. How to deal with this scenario? Send as a JSON perhaps?

Comment: There shouldn't be a <br/> in the textarea, but instead a \n

Comment: hey seems like i was complicating a simple feature (due to lack of awareness). Your suggestion worked like a charm. Thanks very much for clearing some stuff up. cheers!